# CardView binded to worker class returns null

Tags: java, android, cardview

I Have the followin CardView

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout">


                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/mapActivity"
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    tools:context=".Map.MyMap" />

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:id="@+id/cardViewData"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">
    ...
```

Now, I call this CardView in my Activity the this way to get the id of it and pass that CardView to a worker class to handle some logic there with it (I just need to set it visible )

```
private CardView mCardViewData;
```

inside onCreate() , after setContentView

```
 mCardViewData = findViewById(R.id.cardViewData);
        new MapsUtils(this,mCardViewData);
```

As you can see , Im sending this cardview to the worker class where I get it as follow

```
private CardView mCardViewData;

 public MapsUtils(Context context,CardView cardView{

        this.mCardViewData = cardView;
        this.mContext = context;

    }
```

And then Im using it inside MapsUtil in a method like this

```
 private void initRun(){
        mCardViewData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
```

I need to have this cardview binded to my worker class because I manage the logic of the map in a worker class and not in the view.

Now, what I'm getting is this

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'void androidx.cardview.widget.CardView.setVisibility(int)' on a null
>   object reference
>           at com.utils.MapsUtils.initRun(MapsUtils.java:182)
>           at com.utils.MapsUtils.access$000(MapsUtils.java:62)
>           at com.utils.MapsUtils$2.onClick(MapsUtils.java:219)

Error points here

**mCardViewData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);**

And Im trying to see where Im wrong because I just defined all I need to work with that CardView in my worker class

Comment: i think so you should add `android.support.v7.widget.CardView` instead of `androidx.cardview.widget.CardView` in XML

Comment: I'm using androidx libraries, it works the same

Comment: make sure you're caling `initRun()` after initializing `CardView`. error says your `CardView` is not initialized , so its NULL

Comment: hmm let me see.

Comment: yes, Im initializing it after that

Comment: how can not be initialized if I did that inside my onCreate?

Comment: Can ou show the entire java files instead of these chunks please

Comment: @Todd You should initialize CardView first and then call `initRun()` when you need.  You've to show complete code for more help. if error isn't resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem, the problem was that since Im using multiple constructors, the constructor that init a method that calls for the CardView was initializing it without all the elements I needed, now I binded all my elements to that constructor and its working